# iPhone orientation UILabel size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a UILabel inside a UItableviewcell. The width of the label is 280px in portrait mode with a 20px margin on each side. How I can extend the width while keeping the same margin in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```